# Send App to App push notification in android using parse.com

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform, push-notification

I have created a application in android using parse.com to implement push notification. I get notification come successfully from server to my device when I triggers the push button in parse.com

Now My question is that  how can I send the same notification from one device to another using parse.com

Comment: I do it using cloud code

Comment: would you please tell me the exact step to do?

Comment: not sure if my usage matches yours, I send push notifications as a reaction to creating/updating objects. Do you have experience using cloud code already?

Answer (score -1):

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("Giants");
push.setMessage("The Giants just scored! It's now 2-2 against the Mets.");
push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanx suresh but could you please tell me the proper step with code....i am just new in this..

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/Android
Follow this for good tutorial...